# dropping a mongo collection with a "?" at the end of its name

Tags: mongodb

I can't figure out how to drop a collection named "did-it-break?"

I've tried the usual way:

```
db.did-it-break?.drop()
```

but no, its not working. it outputs

```
[thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'break'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with special characters in a Mongo collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569976/working-with-special-characters-in-a-mongo-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reference the collection name using brackets instead of the dot:

```
db['did-it-break?'].drop()
```

Always use brackets if you cannot type some name using the dot notation.