# MongoDB SQL query for table/collections having hyphens (-) in sql-to-mongo-db-query-converter

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database and collections which have hyphens (`-`) in their names.

```
select * 
from test-schema.test-collection;
```

I'm using [sql-to-mongo-db-query-converter](https://github.com/vincentrussell/sql-to-mongo-db-query-converter) dependency to convert above query to mongoDB but it throwing this exception

[image: Exception Image]

I tried using all possible ways like single quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`) and punctuation mark `` (`) ``. It works fine for database if we use below query but it's not working if there is hyphens in collections name.

```
select * 
from "test-schema".test-collection;
```

Comment: You probably want `"test-schema"."test-collection"`.

Comment: @jarlh, Tried it's not working.

Comment: I don't think `"` characters work like that unless you have `set quoted_identifier on` in effect. Have you tried square brackets instead, i.e.: `[test-schema].[test-collection]`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes, tried but same Exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with special characters in a Mongo collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569976/working-with-special-characters-in-a-mongo-collection)

Comment: @SMor, No, It's different issue.